# How to use two loops in recordset to update data

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having two tables which is having claims data and user name respectively
 Tblimport- Contains 10 claim no.s  and. 
tbl_Settings- Contains 3 username
. I want to assign those 10 claims to the 3 users
Condition: same claim should not assign to different users and everyone should get the claims equally. 
I'm planning to use two loops with two record set.
but problem while using do loop it's coming the same claim id to every one

```
strqry = "Select [claimId] from Tblimport"
strqry2 = "Select [username] from tbl_Settings"
rs1.Open strqry2, cn1, adOpenStatic
rs2.Open strqry, cn2, adOpenStatic


rs2.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs2.EOF
If rs1.EOF Then
        rs1.MoveFirst
    End If

    claim = CStr(rs2![ClaimID])
    User = CStr(rs1![UserName])

    Debug.Print claim & "-" & User
        rs1.MoveNext
        If rs1.EOF Then
        rs1.MoveFirst
        End If

    rs2.MoveNext
Loop
```

Output I'm Getting

```
100021245-shp  
100023633-abc  
114552236-kjh
```

In the 4th time while loop coming to `User = CStr(rs1![UserName])` it's showing Run time error 94, invalid usse of null

**Tblimport**
100021245
100023633
114552236
121223333
122333444
112123345
111223344
112344543
322344455

**tbl_Settings**
shp
abc
kjh

Comment: Have you tried using DISTINCT?

Comment: hi dbmitch, where?  in Select Query?

Comment: Oh I see - I thought you were having duplicates issues -  you don;'t show how your data is laid out - you must have a user ID associated with each claim don't you?

Comment: Just reverse the order of the loops if you just want each claim listed with each user

Comment: Dbmitch, i tried by changing the loop order like then not working properly. Then for every users getting only one claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your code mismatched recordsets for the `ClaimID` and `UserId` values.  Or maybe I'm just confused.

Anyway what I think you want is to move through the `ClaimID` values, and for each of those sequentially fetch the "next" `UserId`.  After you've fetched the "last" `UserId`, move back to the first again for the following `ClaimID`.

Sorry I can't think how to describe that more clearly.  But what it come down to is revise your looping strategy.

```vb
rs2.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs2.EOF
    'Claim = CStr(rs1![ClaimID])
    'User = CStr(rs2![UserId])
    Claim = CStr(rs2![ClaimID])
    User = CStr(rs1![UserId])

    Debug.Print Claim & "-" & User

    rs1.MoveNext
    If rs1.EOF Then
        rs1.MoveFirst
    End If
    rs2.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Hi hansup, i will try this code on tomorrow and let u knw. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Hi hansup, its working correctly for upto the 3 rd user. Upto the 3rd user its coming perfectly but its not checking  'if rs1.eof then rs1.movefirst

Comment: Hmm.  My code is intended to replace everything you had after `debug.print Tot2` up util just before `msgbox "Done"`.  Does your current code match that description? Especially does your code still include `Do Until rs1.EOF` and do you have `Loop` in there twice?

Comment: Same way, i have replaced everything after the debug.print tot2 , I'm not using  loop twice. Once the user name completed. Its not checking that if rs1.eof then rs1.movefirst ,

Comment: Then I don't understand why it's not working for you.  I tested those statements in sample code here.  If you post a copy of your database to a file-sharing site, I'll see if I can diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi hansup, I have edited the question and replaced with your code what I have tested.